# Lightning on Burj Khalifa

Tags: electricity, everyday-life, lightning

Does Burj Khalifa, being the tallest building and the best route for lightning, experience most lightning? I suppose lightning in a radius around Burj Khalifa would only fall on it and nowhere else. And don't the people inside the building suffer shock?

Comment: Just because it's the tallest building doesn't mean it's the most suceptable to lightning. It's built near sea level, not on a hill, for example, in an area where stormy weather is less usual.

Answer (score 2):

Usually a building is equipped with a lightning rod that when strike by lightning, will conduct all the current to the ground. This is commonly known as grounding. As the wire conducts the lightning to the ground instead of passing it through the building, the inside of the building is very safe and will not experience any electrocution or fire.

Answer (score 2):

Every high rise is protected from lightning by a lightning arrester.

[image]

It is a rod made of electric conducting material that is projected at a height greater than that of the building, fixed on the terrace. A long metal strip is attached to the rod, which travels all the way to the ground, and is buried in the ground. Many a times, another rod is fixed alongside the lightning arrester, but not attached with it, which has a red light and alerts aircrafts from coming down too low, if flying in that area.

When a lightning strikes, as it is the behaviour of lightning to strike the highest place of conduction in the vicinity, it strikes the conducting rod. The attached strip of the rod conducts the lightning to the ground, insulating the building from the it. Thus, the current is conducted away.

In buildings which are moderately high,  but don't have a lightning conductor, the antennas for television signals become the metallic conductor for lightning, as a result of which the television circuit is burnt. It is always preferred for every house to have a proper conductor for lighting. Otherwise even water pipes from overhead water tanks, if made of metal that conducts, may become a conductor. Check and ensure that your home has one too.

Refer  [here](http://www.electrical-installation.org/enwiki/Building_protection_system). There are three types of lightning conductors mentioned, viz. the conducting rod, conducting wires and Faraday cage. Mostly the rod system is used, as it takes less space and is cost efficient. On buildings where budget is good, and protection is greatly necessary, one may use both the rod and Faraday cage systems. I haven't been to Burj Khalifa, so I can't tell exactly whether both are used.